# Cannot link CSS to HTML file

Tags: html, css

I am trying link up my stylesheet, but I think I am pointing to the wrong file in my html.

My header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jacob Development Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <lin rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
<body>
```

Here is the directory that I put my CSS file in:

```
jacob@jacob-desktop:~/Projects/JacobBlog/blog4/public/stylesheets$ ls
app.css  main.css
```

Comment: what is ` <lin`   ? it's should be a ` link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
```

Please change lin to link

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you will need to close your `<head>` element after all the script and link tags with `</head>`